# C++ error - expected primary expression before 'char' and 'int'

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
class Employee
{
    char name[5];
    int id;
    int age;
    public:
    Employee(char* a, int b, int c)
    {
        strcpy(name, a);
        id=b;
        age=c;
    }
};
class Officer: public Employee
{
    char officer_cadre[3];
    public:
    Officer(char* a, int b, int c, char* d):Employee(char* a, int b, int c)
    {
        strcpy(officer_cadre, d);
    }
};
int main()
{
   Officer o1("Nakul", 1, 2, "ABC");
   return 0;
}
```

The above code is simple, but I'm not able to figure out why the compiler is throwing errors like 'expected primary expression before char' and 'expected primary expression before int'.

Comment: Unrelated but your char arrays are too short. You need one element for the null termination. But better to use `std::string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On this line

```
  Officer(char* a, int b, int c, char* d):Employee(char* a, int b, int c)
```

You should just pass a,b, and c. Instead you are using the syntax to declare a,b, and c. When just referring to them you don't need the types. IE you should do:

```
  Officer(char* a, int b, int c, char* d):Employee(a, b, c)
```

You may have just accidentally copy-pasted the declaration into the child class's constructor.

Comment: Should he allocate memory for `a` and `d`?

Comment: He doesn't have to, since they're just parameters; however, I am concerned about the copies of char* into fixed character strings, which could cause overruns.  strdup (with de-allocation) is a safer bet.

Answer (score 4):

Change this line:

```
Officer(char* a, int b, int c, char* d):Employee(char* a, int b, int c)
```

To this:

```
Officer(char* a, int b, int c, char* d):Employee(a,b,c)
```

Also I am concerned about your declaration of officer_cadre.  It's an array of character pointers, but there's no memory allocation.  Was that the declaration you meant?

Comment: Works fine now! Mistakenly made it an array of char pointers, should have been a character array!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
char* officer_cadre[3];
```

to

```
char officer_cadre[3];
```